# Design icon or logo with lettering like opera max / opera mini / limo app

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, icon

Are there any plugins/fonts in photoshop/illustrator for designing icons like the images below or is it all done by constructing paths ? It would be great if anyone could provide a tutorial or steps for the same. Basically I'm looking for a way to have text like 'O' for opera mini, 'M' for opera max & 'limo' for the limo app rendered as a logo. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: May I suggest you add what you've tried so far?

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 hi! I tried using fonts with really large font size in illustrator and then creating outlines and modifying them.. however it seemed too cumbersome an approach

Comment: Here's a pretty decent answer from elsewhere on the site: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20074/71797 There is the closest I could find to your need. To get the same effect as these icons, you'll need to apply this knowledge to curved shapes.

Comment: Whoever down voted my question, care to leave a reason?

Comment: @visualbear, thank you! That is quite helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just paths with a gradient applied to them. Experiment a bit with shapes with similar gradients, and you'll get a feel for the technique.

Answer (score 1):

I designed limo app logo. I just used a normal font text. And took pen tool in illustrator. I don't remember the font. Any cursive font should work. I picked few parts of font and made them darker.

Comment: oh cool ! thanks man!